# Как объявить static переменную в классе?

Tags: c++, классы, переменные, static

Переменную объявил так:

```
static int workersCount;
```

Однако выдало ошибку:

> [ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'Worker::workersCount' referenced from ...

Comment: Теперь в каком-нибудь .cpp-файле *определите* значение этой переменной: `int имя_класса::workersCount = значение;`

Comment: @Arhad не получается. Выдаёт ещё больше ошибок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объявление статической переменной в определении класса:

```
//some.h
struct SomeType
{
    static int some;
};
```

И последующее определение в одном из .cpp:

```
//some.cpp
#include "some.h"
int SomeType::some = 10;
```

Comment: сделал, как вы сказали, однако выскакивает ещё больше ошибок. Вот одна из них : [BCC32 Error] Unit1.cpp(47): E2089 Identifier 'workersCount' cannot have a type qualifier
  Full parser context
    Unit1.cpp(35): parsing: void _fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *)